# erase functionality in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I need to erase the contents of my canvas. I can achieve this by using 'globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out"'. I have already stored the draw coordinates in my json object, but after erasing I need to update my json object. I tried to capture it's x,y co-ordinate on mouse move (while erasing). Then I matched the same with my previous store object and updated the same. But it's quite a big procedure which causes degradation in my performance. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Please post your code. Preferably also show what you've done in a JSFiddle.net

Comment: this.mousedown = function (event) {
 console.log("mousedown")
 ER.test3 = ER.currentScaleValue;
  var canvas = $(event.target);
  tool.context = event.target.getContext('2d');
  tool.context.beginPath();
     tool.context.moveTo(event._x , event._y );
     tool.obj = new Object();
     tool.obj.x = event._x ;
     tool.obj.y = event._y ;
  tool.obj.z =  ER.currentScaleValue;
     tool.currentCollection.push(tool.obj);
     tool.started = true;
     return false;
 };

Comment: this.mousemove = function (event) {
  if (tool.started) {
  tool.context.lineTo(event._x , event._y );
  tool.context.strokeStyle = 'red';
     tool.context.stroke();
  tool.obj = new Object();
     tool.obj.x = event._x ;
     tool.obj.y = event._y ;
  tool.obj.z =  ER.currentScaleValue;
     tool.currentCollection.push(tool.obj);
  }
   return false;
 };

Comment: this.mouseup = function (event) {
  if (tool.started) {
   tool.mousemove(event);
   tool.started = false;
   var pageID = $(event.target).attr('id').split('_')[1];
   
   ER.pagesCollection.searchCurrentPage(pageID, 'pageNum').get('pencilCollection').push(tool.currentCollection);
   tool.currentCollection = [];

Comment: I wrote above functionality for drawing function after that when I am calling erase functionality again I am storing it's xand y co-ordinate in one array but it's nor working properly

Answer (score 0):

This will clear all contents of your canvas. (Assuming that ctx is your context, and width and height are the width and height of your canvas.

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height)
```